# When & how does logrotate run under Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate

I am new to sysadmining and have a few questions:

1. Where and how is the logrotate procedure initaited by the system?
2. What time of day are my "daily" rotated logfiles being rotated?
3. Do the prerotate commands run for each log file matched in a *.log entry?

Thank you

Comment: You should get some idea from the timestamps on the rotated log files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) My logrotate on my older Hardy install is identical to Mike's answer

2) Looking at the /etc/crontab file, cron.daily is run at 6:25am on my install

3) If the pre-rotate commands are assigned to a a pattern, and the log files match that pattern, then yes

Answer (score 9):

from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles :

> Typically, logrotate is called from
>   the system-wide cron script
>   /etc/cron.daily/logrotate, and further
>   defined by the configuration file
>   /etc/logrotate.conf. Individual
>   configuration files can be added into
>   /etc/logrotate.d (where the apache2
>   and mysql configurations are stored
>   for example).

The files involved are:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate
/etc/logrotate.conf
/ec/logrotate.d/*
```

As with Matt, cron.daily jobs are started at 6:25am on my system, but actual execution time will vary depending on jobs in cron.daily, system load, etc..

**/etc/cron.daily/logrotate** runs logrotate using the logrotate.conf file:

> "/usr/sbin/logrotate
>   /etc/logrotate.conf"

**/etc/logrotate.conf** points to the /etc/logrotate.d directory:

> "include /etc/logrotate.d"

**/etc/logrotate.d** contains individual scripts for specific log files
   For these files, the actions in curly braces (rotate, compress, etc.) are performed on the files defined at the beginning of each block.   Wildcards are allowed, so something like '/var/log/*log' should affect all files in /var/log/ that end with the .log suffix.
If prerotate is one of the keywords used in the block that belongs to '/var/log/*log', then those files will have the prerotate commands run on them, but "only if the log will actually be rotated."(*from* **man logrotate**)

Answer (score 2):

look at the following

```
/etc/cron

ls /etc/cron.daily
```

In RedHat is is

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

Comment: OK, i see the file in cron.daily.  A quick check to /etc/crontab shows when that is scheduled to run.  Thank you